# How to extract micr code from bank cheques accurately using google vision api?

Tags: express, google-cloud-vision

[micr code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRj9k.png) I want to extract MICR codes from bank cheques using google vision api ,currently vision API is not giving adequate results specially it is not reading the fonts of MICR correctly. How to use this API more appropriately so that I can extract MICR accurately.

Comment: It might not be possible to get a solution to your use case using Google's Vision API. The codes that you want to extract are designed to not be easily OCR-ed. Just like a captcha code.

Comment: @CosminCretu by any another tech stack can I extract this micr code??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great implementation using OpenCV.

[Part 1 from pyimagesearch blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/24/bank-check-ocr-with-opencv-and-python-part-i/)

[Part 2 from pyimagesearch blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/31/bank-check-ocr-opencv-python-part-ii/)